# Are there any examples of Jesus praying publicly?

Tags: life-of-jesus, prayer

As a follow up to this question:

[Is it ok to pray in public?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/is-it-ok-to-pray-in-public/17725#17725)

There are many examples where Jesus prays privately and he will intentionally separate himself from his disciples, but are there examples where he actually prays out loud (not including the Lord's prayer where he is not actually praying but teaching the disciples how to pray)?

Comment: Outside Lazarus' grave and John 7 come to mind.

Comment: I think you mean John 11, but good point.

Comment: I actually meant [John 17](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john%2017&version=ESV). Nice catch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When Jesus fed the 5,000, the Gospel of John records that Jesus took the bread and gave thanks:

> Jesus then took the loaves, and when he had given thanks, he distributed them to those who were seated. So also the fish, as much as they wanted.  John 6:11 ESV

Additionally, in Mark's account of Jesus feeding the 4,000, Jesus again gives thanks, presumably in a public setting:

> And he directed the crowd to sit down on the ground. And he took the seven loaves, and having given thanks, he broke them and gave them to his disciples to set before the people; and they set them before the crowd.  Mark 8:6 ESV

So, Jesus does appear to pray publicly, albeit not to make a show as the Pharisees did.  In this case, it appears to be private prayer prayed in public.

> And when you pray, you must not be like the hypocrites. For they love to stand and pray in the synagogues and at the street corners, that they may be seen by others. Truly, I say to you, they have received their reward.  Matthew 6:5 ESV

So, it does not seem reasonable to conclude that it is wrong to pray in public.  Indeed, it is more reasonable to conclude that it is right to pray in both public and private settings, as long as it is with a right heart and not done for show.

Comment: You make an interesting point about private prayers prayed in a public setting. It would be difficult to say whether or not this is always the case.

Answer (score 4):

He prayed in public over the fish and bread, "Jesus then took the loaves, and having given thanks..." [John 6:11a].

The "high priestly prayer" of John 17 starts, "Jesus spoke these things; and lifting up His eyes to heaven, He said..."

Given that He also taught in the synagogues, it seems highly likely He prayed frequently in public (though never to "be like the hypocrites; for they love to stand and pray in the synagogues and on the street corners so that they may be seen by men. Truly I say to you, they have their reward in full." [Matthew 6:5])

Answer (score 3):

JESUS prayed publicly even from the cross...

> "FATHER forgive them for they know not what they do!"

If no one had heard it, none could report it as a prayer!

Answer (score 0):

I would not say its "wrong" to pray publicly.However, one should avoid such and there is little to no value in it. I only find Jesus praying publicly one time, John 17. Giving thanks does not qualify imho as public prayer.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This is an okay answer, but the community here prefers longer answers. Please see [Guidelines for writing effective answers](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1920/guidelines-for-writing-effective-answers) and [What is a well-sourced, dispassionate answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/886/what-is-a-well-sourced-dispassionate-answer) After that, please [edit] this post to make it better. I hope to see you post again soon.

Answer (score 0):

Praying is different from giving thanks.

> Jesus then took the loaves, and when he had given thanks, he
>   distributed them to those who were seated. So also the fish, as much
>   as they wanted. John 6:11 ESV

how about..

> "FATHER forgive them for they know not what they do!"

Jesus cannot go down from the cross and pray in private at this time.

So, why you should pray in private. Because praying is asking earnestly, begging, communicating with God. So you should do it without distractions.

> And when you pray, you must not be like the hypocrites. For they love
>   to stand and pray in the synagogues and at the street corners, that
>   they may be seen by others. Truly, I say to you, they have received
>   their reward. Matthew 6:5 ESV

So, praying and broadcasting it in TV is wrong! For they have received their reward.

For guidance, if you want to pray at public, keep it secret. If someone complements you like, "wow, you are a holy man." Then you have received your reward.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: What about the many mentions in Acts where the Apostles pray *together*? I've never been to a church where they did not also do this. A church that televises their service is doing the same thing also. On this site, we don't make judgments that are outside of the scope of the site. This is not a Church site; it is an academic site. Reference: [Brothers, we are not Christians‼](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/193)

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)